# MergeRecord based on schema; only merge records of the same schema

Tags: schema, apache-nifi, parquet, database-schema

My use-case is:

1. Have API credentials
2. Use `UpdateAttribute` to update (1) schema, (2) s3 location/bucket etc.
3. Query API endpoint for records
4. Paginate API for more records
5. Call `MergeRecord`
6. Parquet out to `PutS3Object`

Since 3, 4, 5, 6 are all the same, I am re-using processors like (screenshot).  My problem is (5) `MergeRecord` will try to merge different schemas together as queue items will flow in randomly from the funnel, which is obviously a problem.

How can I restructure this?  I'd like to re-use processors as much as possible (DRY), but still be able to add more schemas as my needs evolve.

[image: my nifi flows]

Comment: try loading the schema as an attribute and use that attribute to merge the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `Correlation Attribute Name`, setting it to `${schema.name}` and it's working as expected.

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.MergeRecord/index.html

> If specified, two FlowFiles will be binned together only if they have the same value for this Attribute. If not specified, FlowFiles are bundled by the order in which they are pulled from the queue.